# Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes (MySQL using PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller

I am trying to make an amazon type mock web application. I am currently stuck on my adding a product section because every time I try adding a product it pulls up this error *Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[08S01]: Communication link failure: 1153 Got a packet bigger than max_allowed_packet bytes*. I am not sure how to fix this in my code. Here is my code:

```
<?php
require_once('database_controller.php');
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../model/product/product.php');

class ProductController extends DatabaseController
{

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function create_product(Product $product): int /* 0 => success / 2 => error on query */
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO product (seller_account_id, name, description, price, category, type_of_sale, thumbnail, image_1, image_2, image_3, image_4, end_of_auction, account_id_last_proposal_auction) VALUES (:seller_account_id,:name,:description,:price,:category,:type_of_sale,:thumbnail,:image_1,:image_2,:image_3,:image_4,:eoa,:author_auction)";


    $query = $this->_database->prepare($sql);
    $res = $query->execute(array(
        'seller_account_id' => $product->get_seller_account_id(),
        'name' => $product->get_name(),
        'description' => $product->get_description(),
        'price' => $product->get_price(),
        'category' => $product->get_category(),
        'type_of_sale' => $product->get_type_of_sale(),
        'thumbnail' => $product->get_thumbnail(),
        'image_1' => $product->get_image1(),
        'image_2' => $product->get_image2(),
        'image_3' => $product->get_image3(),
        'image_4' => $product->get_image4(),
        'eoa' => $product->get_end_of_auction(),
        'author_auction' => $product->get_account_id_last_proposal_auction()
    ));

    return $res ? 0 : 2;
}

public function delete_product(int $product_id): bool
{
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM product WHERE id = :pid';

    $query = $this->_database->prepare($sql);

    return $query->execute(array('pid' => $product_id));
}

public function get_last_produces(int $count): ?array
{
    $sql = 'SELECT * from product ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT :count';

    $query = $this->_database->prepare($sql);

    if (!$query->execute(array('count' => $count)))
        return null;

    return $query->fetchAll();
}

public function get_product(int $id): ?Product
{
    $sql = 'SELECT * from product WHERE id = :id';

    $query = $this->_database->prepare($sql);

    if (!$query->execute(array('id' => $id)))
        return null;
    $data = $query->fetch();

    return $data == null ? null : new Product($data);
}

public function get_all_products(int $seller_account_id): ?array
{
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM product WHERE seller_account_id = :id';

    $query = $this->_database->prepare($sql);

    if (!$query->execute(array('id' => $seller_account_id)))
        return null;

    return $query->fetchAll();
}

public function update_price(int $product_id, float $new_price, int $author_auction): bool
{
    $sql = 'UPDATE product SET price = :new_price, account_id_last_proposal_auction = :aid WHERE id = :pid';

    $query = $this->_database->prepare($sql);

    return $query->execute(array(
        'new_price' => $new_price,
        'pid' => $product_id,
        'aid' => $author_auction
    ));
}

public function get_products(string $category, string $filter): ?array
{
    if ($category == 'all' && $filter == '') {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM product';

        $query = $this->_database->prepare($sql);

        if (!$query->execute())
            return null;

        return $query->fetchAll();
    } elseif ($filter == '' && $category != 'all') {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM product WHERE category = :category';

        $query = $this->_database->prepare($sql);

        if (!$query->execute(array('category' => $category == 'suits' ? 1 : 2)))
            return null;

        return $query->fetchAll();
    } elseif ($category == 'all' && $filter != '') {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE name LIKE '%$filter%'";

        $query = $this->_database->prepare($sql);

        if (!$query->execute())
            return null;

        return $query->fetchAll();
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE name LIKE '%$filter%' AND category = :category";

        $query = $this->_database->prepare($sql);

        if (!$query->execute(array('category' => $category == 'suits' ? 1 : 2)))
            return null;

        return $query->fetchAll();
    }
}
}
```

The error is in this part of the code :

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO product (seller_account_id, name, description, price, category, type_of_sale, thumbnail, image_1, image_2, image_3, image_4, end_of_auction, account_id_last_proposal_auction) VALUES (:seller_account_id,:name,:description,:price,:category,:type_of_sale,:thumbnail,:image_1,:image_2,:image_3,:image_4,:eoa,:author_auction)";


$query = $this->_database->prepare($sql);
$res = $query->execute(array(
    'seller_account_id' => $product->get_seller_account_id(),
    'name' => $product->get_name(),
    'description' => $product->get_description(),
    'price' => $product->get_price(),
    'category' => $product->get_category(),
    'type_of_sale' => $product->get_type_of_sale(),
    'thumbnail' => $product->get_thumbnail(),
    'image_1' => $product->get_image1(),
    'image_2' => $product->get_image2(),
    'image_3' => $product->get_image3(),
    'image_4' => $product->get_image4(),
    'eoa' => $product->get_end_of_auction(),
    'author_auction' => $product->get_account_id_last_proposal_auction()
));
```

How would I go on about fixing this.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should increase this session setting. For example, twice, by `SET SESSION max_allowed_packet := @@max_allowed_packet + @@max_allowed_packet ;` executed in the connection before the query which causes this error.

But in your case this is not a solution. You save 4 images into the table which is bad practice.

You should at least normalize your structure and create separate table for images which stores main row identifier (reference to `product` table), image number (1..4) and the image... but the best way is to store images in the filesystem and save name/path into the database.